# Android: How to detect Home button pressed with logs?

Tags: android, logging

I have read another questions about Home-Button and his detection possibilities. I also know that there are no broadcast intents for this actions. I try to track it with logcat, but I have not really an idea what the message should  I track. I read logs about one hour, but  I couldn't find a messages that really says now it would be definitely Home-Button pressed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Home-Button is pressed, `system_process` with Tag `ActivityManager` start the Home activity with an Intent whose format may like this

```
Intent { 
    act=android.intent.action.MAIN 
    cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] 
    flg=0x10200000
    cmp=com.android.launcher/.Launcher 
}
```

You can filter this in `logcat`. It seems that you can simulate Home-Button's action, but can not get Home-Button's Intent, so when this shows, it may `definitely` Home-Button pressed.

Hope this help you.

Comment: I have some little problem now. I use just exec logcat and it gives me not only new logs, but also the log history. Are there some possibility  to became only new logs?

Comment: DDMS has a "Clear Log" button. ADB has a command `adb logcat -c`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add a call to `Log.i()` in the onResume of the Home activity?

Comment: my app starts PlayStore and I need to know if the user press Home-Button.

Comment: You asked about logging the fact someone has tapped the Home button. If you have a more specific question, ask it, and please don't waste peoples' time by not providing enough information.

Comment: @Aprel you have no way to find out what the user pressed while inside another app

Comment: @zapl There is one way to get it information --> with read of logs. I though that you know it.

Comment: @Ollie C yes, I need some help to find the associated message.  You had all information, that you need. I asked how to find this information. And you asked me why I don´t use the simplest method to do that and I answered you.

Comment: @Aprel fire up logcat, don't filter out any message and try to find a messages that happens once you hit home. There might be a message about `android.intent.category.HOME` but there is no guarantee that this works.

Comment: It is not right that app can never know what user pressed. For example, app can detect a back key press. But the pressing of Home key is not delieverd to a user app .It is handled by framework and never delivered to apps. It has to be detected from Logs .